# New Java project structure Help needed

Tags: java, eclipse

I am not so aware of the java project structure. I have few selenium tests which I want to write in java. So I have chosen eclipse as my editor. Here I wan to create a new java project with proper folder structure as I am planning to add few more java classes in future.

Please let me know how to create an idea java project in eclipse. I have seen people create something like com.org.project_name etc and then src , resources directories inside that.

I am not able to make any sense out of those. Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java you can create packages. Simply said packages are folders that contain classes.

The statement `import java.net.Socket` means: from the folder `java/net` import the class named `Socket`.

The statement `package myApplication.util.SuperCounter` means that the class `SuperCounter` can be found under `myApplication/util` folder.

Packages are an easy way to organize your work. Because in a big project you will have class name collisions (i.e. classes that use the same name). With packages you can avoid it.

Also Java supports default (private, public, protected). Default methods, attributes, classes can only be seen by elements in the same package!

Answer (score 3):

The software project management tool **Apache Maven** recommends, uses and expects a common directory layout that can be considered as *best practise*.

An overview can be found here: [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Comment: +1 for maven. i think it is best investment learning maven while you study on folder structures.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse should create the proper folders for you...here is an example
http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-New-Java-Project-in-Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a Java Project then go to File -> New -> Java Project.

If its web application then, select Dynamic Web Project.

These will automatically create the required structures.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Java you work in packages, which define the scope of your classes, and is basically the only thing you should really be concentrating on in the beginning. There's a good article on the subject here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html